# SAS PRXCHANGE a number between words into similar number of spaces

Tags: regex, sas

Is it possible to use the number in this string:

'xx8xx'

by replacing the number with 8 spaces to get this string:

```
'xx        xx'
```

I can identify the number between the xx but the replacement syntax does not work as intended:

```
PRXCHANGE(s/xx([\d]*)xx/' ' x $1/io, -1, 'xx8xx')
```

Is there a way to use the number being held in $1 to repeat the space character by that number i.e. something like ' ' x $1?

Any help much appreciated!
Tiaan

Comment: mmm the number of spaces in line 4 has been reduced to 1, it should be 8 spaces ><

Comment: In SAS 9, PCRE regexps are used, but even that does not let you use the pattern like that. You cannot evaluate the group contents in the string replacement part. You'd need to write some code around that.

Comment: Seems you are correct that it cannot be done in a single statement, thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposed you need to replace with three blank.

```
data _null_;
  x=prxchange('s/(xx)\d+(xx)/$1   $2/', -1, 'xx8xx');
  _x=prxchange('s/(?=\w+)(\d+)/   /',1,'xx8xx');
  put _all_;
run;
```

**Edit:**
I missed important information. Tranwrd and repeat could be used to get it.

```
data _null_;
   x=tranwrd('xx8xx', prxchange('s/.*(\d+).*/$1/',1,'xx8xx'), repeat(' ',prxchange('s/.*(\d+).*/$1/',1,'xx8xx')));
   put _all_;
run;
```

Comment: Interesting solution (the second one), it works (had to add -1 as it created 9 spaces) for my purposes.

    x=tranwrd('xx8xx', prxchange('s/.*(\d+).*/$1/',1,'xx8xx'), repeat(' ',prxchange('s/.*(\d+).*/$1/',1,'xx8xx')-1));

Thank you Sheglin!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extract first, then compile a new regex.  This will be expensive since you have to compile once per line.

```
data have;
input xstr $;
datalines;
xx8xx
xx3xx
xx4xx
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  rx1 = prxparse('/xx([\d])*xx/io');
  rc1 = prxmatch(Rx1,xstr);
  num_x = prxposn(rx1,1,xstr);

  rx2 = prxparse(cat('s/(xx)[\d]*(xx)/$1',repeat(" ",num_x-1),'$2/i'));
  newstr = prxchange(rx2,-1,xstr);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, have not fully tested your solution as it is a bit more verbose than Shenglin's